# If I ask a yes/no question, am I able to give it a value and add to calculations?

Tags: cognito-forms, formulas

Question on my form:

> Is your wedding on a holiday?

If they answer yes, I'd like to add a $100 value to that answer and then add it to the total.

Is this possible?

If so, how?

Comment: What web application are you talking about?

Comment: I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. I would like to get a bit more information about what you are looking to do. Would you be able to provide us more information via our support request (https://help.cognitoforms.com/support).